# Printscreen automatically to image

Tags: windows, images, screenshot

Is it possible by pressing <kbd>PrintScreen</kbd> button to save image as JPEG, or other format? Without going to Paint, pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but you'll have to use some third party tool to do that in Windows.

Personally, I use this free utility: http://screencapturer.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Greenshot](http://getgreenshot.org). It offers you a list of actions to perform after you take a screenshot:

[image]

Alternatively, you can configure it to always use a specific action (like saving to a predefined location).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 10 and higher just press <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>Print Screen</kbd>. There's also another new shortcut <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to save and edit the screenshot using Snipping Tool